# removing hyperlink title - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, header, themes

After being googling I found many results like this.

Search for: `<a href="<? php the_permalink()" /> <?php the_title()?> </a>`

in single.php or page.php or index.php inside your theme dir.

No way I can find (just looking for title, not the whole sentence).

I'm using Fastfood theme, and I have been looking in single.php, page.php and index.php (all of these files are 1 or 2Kb, so there is no way Im failing in my search.

'C:...\apache2\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\fastfood\' this is dir where Im looking at.

Does anybody know in which file/dir I have to look into?

Thanks for your time folks.

EDIT: Neither in header.php, but close enough:

Comment: Check into the header.php

Comment: uhmm close, in header.php I only can edit the title refering to rss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `functions.php` find the function called `fastfood_featured_title`. Change the following line:

```
if ( $post_title || $thumb ) $post_title = '<h2 class="' . $title_class . '"><a title="' . $args['title'] . '" href="' . $args['href'] . '"' . $link_target . ' rel="bookmark">' . $thumb . $post_title . '</a></h2>';
```

to:

```
if ( $post_title || $thumb ) $post_title = '<h2 class="' . $title_class . '">' . $thumb . $post_title . '</h2>';
```

Comment: I knew your answer was right but I couldnt confirmed cuz W7 was showing up some error at the time to edit *.php.

Thanks for your time. Are you fastfood theme user?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux or MacSOX you can use the `find`command, open a terminal, go into your theme folder and type

```
find . -type f -name \*.php -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i the_title()
```

You will see where the `the_title()` is used, and then you can modify it

With Windows - wich i don't really know, check that link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/017ybd7t(v=VS.80).aspx

### EDIT

The alternative of `find`in Windoze seems to be `findstr`, try something like

FINDSTR /s /i the_title() *.php

Comment: Im under W7. Neither I use Visual Studio 2005/Visual SourceSafe